# UDP receiver in C (using Winsock)

Tags: c, sockets, udp, winsock2

I'm trying to learn socket programming in C using winsock libraries. I managed to knock up the following simple example:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<WinSock2.h>
#include<conio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define BUFFERSZ 1024
#define PORT 19010  

typedef enum
{
    BLOCKING = 0,
    NONBLOCKING = 1
} BLOCKING_MODE;

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in UserApp;
    struct sockaddr_in Server;

    int ServerLen = sizeof(Server);
    int ReceivedDataLen;
    UINT8 ReceiveBuffer[BUFFERSZ];

    WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ListenSocket;
    UINT32 Mode = (UINT32)NONBLOCKING;
    UINT32 bufferdata;

    int loop;

    if (WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData) == 0)
    {
        /* Create UDP socket */
        if ((ListenSocket = WSASocketW(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            int SocketOption = 1;
            setsockopt(ListenSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&SocketOption, sizeof(SocketOption));

            UserApp.sin_family = AF_INET;
            UserApp.sin_port = htons(PORT);
            UserApp.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

            // Bind socket
            if (bind(ListenSocket, (PSOCKADDR)&UserApp, sizeof(UserApp)) != SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                /* Using ioctlsocket() */
                if (ioctlsocket(ListenSocket, FIONBIO, &Mode) != SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    ioctlsocket(ListenSocket, FIONREAD, &bufferdata);

                    /* Read data from buffer */
                    if (bufferdata != 0)
                    {
                        ReceivedDataLen = recvfrom(ListenSocket, ReceiveBuffer, BUFFERSZ, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&Server, &ServerLen);
                    }

                    /* Display received data */
                    printf("\n%d :: \n", __LINE__);
                    for (loop = 0; loop < ReceivedDataLen; loop++)
                    {
                        printf("%02X ", ReceiveBuffer[loop]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }

                /* Using select() */
                FD_SET ReadSet;
                FD_ZERO(&ReadSet);

                FD_SET(ListenSocket, &ReadSet);

                struct timeval TimeOut;
                TimeOut.tv_usec = 100000; /* 0.1sec timeout */
                bufferdata = 0;
                bufferdata = select(0, &ReadSet, NULL, NULL, &TimeOut);

                if (bufferdata != 0)
                {
                    ReceivedDataLen = recvfrom(ListenSocket, ReceiveBuffer, BUFFERSZ, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &Server, &ServerLen);
                }

                /* Display received data */
                printf("\n%d :: \n", __LINE__);
                for (loop = 0; loop < ReceivedDataLen; loop++)
                {
                    printf("%02X ", ReceiveBuffer[loop]);
                }
                printf("\n");

                closesocket(ListenSocket);
            }
        }
    }   

    WSACleanup();

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

It does compile under Visual Studio 2017.

I have an application transmitting UDP on localhost:19010. When I run it using visual studio it does not seem to receive any messages sent by the application.

However, when I single-step through the code, it seems to receive and process (display) the UDP packets.

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: At which frequency did the server application send upd packets? May be your timeout is too small?<br> Note that you try to read from socket only when `select` returns `0`, but `select` returns `0` only on timeout, it returns `SOCKET_ERROR (-1)` on error condition.

Comment: Do you really want to receive  ''one'' datagram with such effort? I assume you want to implement a loop that calls `select` and `recvfrom` multiple times.

Comment: @purplepsycho, harper: This code snippet is intended to be part of a bigger application. The application has a scheduler that would schedule the UDP receive/process functionality (similar to the one above) every 100ms. The server is expected to send events/messages asynchronously. I'm trying to develop a functionality that would check if UDP datagram is received from the server in the current frame and if so, process it. It is a single-threaded system so I'm trying to use the same timeout period as the parent scheduler rate. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Neil: "*I'm trying to develop a functionality that would check if UDP datagram is received from the server in the current frame and if so, process it*" - on each scheduled check, call `select()` with a 0ms timeout, and if the return value is > 0 then read a packet from the socket.